# Is this piecewise-defined function on $\mathbb{R}^2$ continuous at $(0,0)$? What about differentiable?

Tags: calculus, general-topology, derivatives

Is this function is a differentiable function, a continuous function at the point $(0,0)$?
How to show that ?

$$
f(x,y)=\begin{cases}
\frac{x^{3}y+xy^{3}}{x^{2}+y^{4}} &\text{if }(x,y)\neq (0,0),\\ 
0 & \text{if }(x,y)=(0,0)
\end{cases}
$$

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Is the denominator correct? Are you sure it shouldn't be $x^2 + y^4$ (or some other combination involving *both* $x$ and $y$)?

Comment: @  mrf Thanks! You are right is was mistake in denominator...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an unusual question, but a great one. @guru's method still applies. You should be able to argue continuity.

For differentiability, note that both partials at the origin are $0$. So you need to consider
$$\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0} \frac {f(x,y)}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} \overset{?}= 0\,.$$
The polar coordinates approach should address this as well.

Comment: Thanks,but I didn't succeed to show that the function is continuous by expressing it in polar coordinates. Can you please help me?

Comment: Put $x=r\cos\theta$ and $y=r\sin\theta$, plug in, and simplify *somewhat* — in particular, what power of $r$ ends up factoring out?

Answer (score 2):

No it is not continuous. Hence also not differentiable. Express it in polar coordinates. Cancel common terms from numerator and denominator. Try approaching zero along different paths, you will get different values. For eg., along the path $\theta=0$ you get the value zero. Whereas along the path $\theta=\pi/2$ you will get infinity.

Comment: Sorry! There was a mistake in denominator...

Answer (score 2):

Then it is continuous at 0 through similar reasoning. Don't know about differentiability it is a bit tedious so I didnt do it you have to work it out in a similar way.

Comment: You should delete your earlier answer to avoid confusing the OP.

Comment: @ guru Thank you. But I didn't succeed to show that the function is continuous by expressing it in polar coordinates. Can you please help me?